# New/edited fields not showing up after editing ACF field group

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am managing an existing site, with working ACF - there are several field groups set up, one of which is for Team Members- We want to add an additional field to the custom fields for Team Members for an alternate image.

I have set the new image field up - as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

But when I attempt to add/edit a new team member, the new fields do not appear in the editor - as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening? I have disabled other plugins and reactivated them, I have updated to the latest ACF also, nothing seems to make the new fields appear in the editors.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. I think you would be better off asking support from the ACF builders.

Comment: Turned out it was some code overriding the settings.

I did eventually figure it out by tracing my way through the entire theme's code.

My question perhaps should have also asked if there were any ways of overriding by coding/programming, as that was really the only possibility left at that point. I put the question on here in case maybe someone out there may have known about the code override.

Answer (score 0):

ACF settings can actually be overwritten by code added to the functions.php file using a combination of built in filters for ACF such as acf_load_listing_type_source and acf_add_local_field_group.

Anyone running into this issue should confirm that this is not the case. It happened to me as I am editing a client's website and I did not actually create the theme, so was unaware of the code overriding the ACF settings.